# Given a function with widespread zero tails: Cut down the plotting range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'd like to plot  (using `matplotlib.pyplot`) a probability density function (pdf), but hide their left and/or right tail whenever these are fairly close to zero.
E.g., the normal distribution when being apart some multiples of the standard deviation from the mean value.

The pdf is stored in two arrays `samplingPts` and `functionVals`, 
containing the equidistant sampling point coordinates and the values of the function, respectively.
Both arrays are of type `numpy.ndarray` and have identical length.
Until now I use a quick and dirty hack by just cutting down the arrays:

```
# Define shortened arrays by dropping indices whose
# corresponding value.__abs__() is below a given threshold
threshold = 0.005
samplingPts_shortened  =  samplingPts[scipy.absolute(functionVals) > threshold]
functionVals_shortened = functionVals[scipy.absolute(functionVals) > threshold]
```

Very dirty indeed, it cannot be the final clue because the pdf possibly has two or more humps and may be close to zero in between, whence the "in-between sampling points" were eliminated as well. But they should remain and be present in the plot.
In addition it is not at all memory saving.

**So my question is** how to implement sound code which, 
given two arrays as of above representing the function, cuts down these arrays at both ends until the function values begin to notably emerge from zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not look from the beginning of the `samplingPts` for when `functionVals` increases above the threshold, and cut it off there. Then look from the end of `samplingPts` backwards for when `functionVals` increases above the threshold and cut it off there too?

Something like:

```
for i in range(len(samplingPts)):
    if scipy.absolute(functionVals[i]) > threshold:
        break
samplingPts = samplingPts[i:]
functionVals = functionVals[i:]

for i in range(len(samplingPts)-1, 0, -1)):
    if scipy.absolute(functionVals[i]) > threshold:
        break
samplingPts = samplingPts[:i+1]
functionVals = functionVals[:i+1]
```

Comment: This is a natural proposal. I just integrated the snippets successfully into my code, further benefitting from the fact that for the plot the sought subarray is only temporalily needed:

`plot(samplingPts[lowIdx:highIdx+1], functionVals[lowIdx:highIdx+1], label= "pdf")`
All in all it's a Sharp solution indeed, John, thank you!

Upvote will happen once my rep score allows for that.